# I need to display zoomed in version of the image(along with description), that our mouse is hovering on in a separate area

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is a list of images. Once I hover over an image, the image and description of that image should be rendered on top of the page. I have got suggestions which will zoom the image itself, but did not get how to implement this scenario, where in, I need to display the zoomed-in version along with description on top of the page(On hovering over the image). Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CSS3 - transform` property

HTML Code

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="image">
        <img  src="http://placehold.it/320x240" alt="Some awesome text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.thumbnail {
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}

.image img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.image:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.25);
}
```

you could use `zoom` property as well, but you'd be restricted to only IE browser.